# How to Debug this logcat exception

Tags: android

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x6d in tid 2058 (ModernAsyncTask)

  [ 03-16 13:36:48.406   607:  607 W/]
debuggerd: handling request: pid=1940 uid=10343 gid=10343 tid=2058
```

I get this exception on my app, and the app crashes. I am not sure what to make out of it or how to debug this. Any input would be much appreciated. Also i am not using NDK in the project.

Comment: i think this is not a exception.

Comment: show your complete logcat.

Comment: that is it, as soon as i get this in logcat, the app gets stuck and crashes

Comment: then show your activity code.

Comment: it is quit a few fragments working together, one thing i can tell is this includes a map fragment